# Parse json file without key values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm trying to parse a json file with `Json.net`. The content of the json file is:

```
[
  [ "240521000", "37.46272", "25.32613", "0", "71", "90", "15", "2016-07-18T21:09:00" ],
  [ "237485000", "37.50118", "25.23968", "177", "211", "273", "8", "2015-09-18T21:08:00" ]
]
```

I created the following code:

```
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string json = wc.DownloadString("data.json");
    dynamic myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

    foreach (string item in myObject[0])
    {
        var x = item[0];

    }
```

How can I loop through all the  individual items without having a key?

Comment: Is the JSON you posted correct? It shows a two-dimensional array ([][]), but the content of the nested array looks like it should be an object, instead - usually noted by { } instead.

Comment: @MadsTaanquist The json is coming from: http://www.marinetraffic.com/nl/ais-api-services/documentation/api-service:27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While diiN_'s answer answers the question, I don't think it's a good solution. Having had a look at the Marine Traffic API, it feels like they've made a poor JSON implementation, as the XML representation clearly has attribute names for the values. Their JSON should've been:

```
{"positions": ["position": {"mmsi": "311029000", "lat": "37.48617", "long": "24.37233", ...}]}
```

Because it isn't, we have a JSON string instead where it's a nested array, where the array is a two-dimensional array, and you'd have to hope the data model isn't changed to remove something, as you'd have to use an index to retrieve data.

However, if you look at the XML available from the API, the attributes have names. I would suggest that you instead download the XML, and parse this into an object - a model, in ASP.NET - which is strongly typed, and can be used more easily in a View.

Here's an example that I've got running. It uses XML parsing to first read the XML from the API, and then parse it to JSON, and finally an actual object.

**First, the model class (Position.cs)**

```
public sealed class Position
{
    [JsonProperty("@MMSI")]
    public string MMSI { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@LAT")]
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@LON")]
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@SPEED")]
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@HEADING")]
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@COURSE")]
    public string Course { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@STATUS")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@TIMESTAMP")]
    public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Next, the parsing logic:

```
var client = new WebClient();
var xml = client.DownloadString("data.xml");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var positions = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("pos").SelectToken("row").ToObject<List<Position>>();
```

At the end of the parsing logic, you now have a list of Positions which you can pass to your view, and have it be strongly typed.

As a brief example:

```
// after you have the positions list
return View(positions);
```

**Positions.cshtml**

```
@model List<Positions>

<h2>Positions</h2>
@foreach (var position in Model)
{
    <p>@position.MMSI (@position.Latitude, @position.Longitude)</p>
}
```

I hope this is useful to you. If you have any questions, drop me a comment.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation!

Answer (score 3):

You probably just need two nested `foreach` statements. Try something like this:

```
foreach (var items in myObject)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```